# echo array without last item in php

Tags: php, arrays

Does anyone know how to not echo the last item in an array? I'm really new to php.

Here is the part I'm having trouble with:

```
...

return($keywords);

}

$words = (mixer(strtolower($keywordlist)));
$query =  implode(',', $words);
echo('Search query: ' . $query . PHP_EOL);
$query = rawurlencode($query);
echo('Encoded: ' . $query . PHP_EOL);
***trying to remove last item in array from showing here***
echo('Without Last: ' . $query . PHP_EOL);
```

If I put `array_shift($query);` or `array_pop($query);` or `array_shift($array,1,-1));` were the stars are I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/content/14/7557914/html/test2.php on line 102 
line 102 = echo('Without Last: ' . $query . PHP_EOL);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error would indicate that there is something wrong on line _101_, making the `echo` unexpected. In general, you should provide complete, minimal testcases for this stuff. Annotated snippets are insufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you don't have an array.  You already imploded it, so it is a string.  You'd need to `array_pop($words)`, then `implode(',',$words)`.... not `$query`.